# Highlight compilation error in compilation mode buffer

Tags: terminal-emacs, compilation-mode

I know how to highlight the source code corresponding to the
selected `compilation-mode` error.  I also know about the little
arrow in the fringe that points to the error in the compilation
buffer, and that if the fringe is not visible, next-error will
show the error right at the top of the window to indicate which
error is selected.

What I want to know instead is: How can I highlight the selected
error *in the compilation-mode buffer* with a face that I can
customize?

I want this because I want to see where I've jumped to when I
both:

1. am running emacs in a terminal (`-nw`)
2. have `compilation-context-lines` set to some high value like 15
   so I can see a whole Python traceback rather than just the last line

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I have a simple modified version of `hl-line-mode` active in buffer that shows my error messages -- usually dealing with Grep results.  And, I set the face to just a yellow underline.  And, my custom version adds an overlay-arrow-bitmap / fringe indicator in the left fringe of wherever point is at.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot that depicts grep results, with surrounding context lines in grey, error lines in royal blue (sandwiched between context above and below), error line number in red, divider dashes in plain default white, overlay-arrow-bitmap of a dark blue arrow at point, and a yellow underline of a modified `hl-line-mode` wherever I move my point (either manually with an arrow key, or by jumping next/previous error):   https://lawlist.com/images/example_compilation.png .  If something in that screenshot looks appealing and you need assistance achieving it, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @lawlist the yellow line looks appealing!  But I don't understand how to achieve it, because while `next-error` (with `-nw` at least) scrolls the compilation window and sets its current line, face `hl-line` doesn't get applied to the new current line (and removed from the old one) until I switch to the compilation window (but I basically never have the cursor in the compilation window).

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about the ability to call `next-error`/`previous-error` from the source file.  I was unaware of that feature.  Here is one idea:  Enable `hl-line-mode` in the compilation buffer, which can be enabled automatically by turning it on with the `compilation-mode-hook`; e.g., `(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook (lambda () (hl-line-mode 1)))`.  And, then add this to your `.emacs`/`init.el` file:  `(defun my-func () (with-current-buffer next-error-last-buffer (when hl-line-mode (hl-line-highlight)))) (add-hook 'next-error-hook 'my-func)`

Comment: To the extent you want to write a custom function to run your own highlighting stuff in the compilation mode buffer, the following variables can be used from the `next-error-hook` to get the location of point in the compilation buffer:  `compilation-current-error` and `overlay-arrow-position`, both of which are markers.  Here is a message that prints the values for the markers:  `(defun my-func () (with-current-buffer next-error-last-buffer (message "%d | %d" (marker-position overlay-arrow-position) (marker-position compilation-current-error)))) (add-hook 'next-error-hook 'my-func)`

Comment: @lawlist yes that's actually a straightforward suggestion to switch to the buffer to update the face display that I missed -- having learned from you about `hl-line-mode` I was just stuck on thinking there must be another way I think.  `next-error` outside of compilation-mode is, by the way, a very useful feature IMO -- at least for programmers, for navigating stack frames (also, OMG I taught lawlist something about emacs, made my day).  Thanks also re the other state I could use.  I'll try to turn this into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From lawlist's comment (this works nicely in both terminal and GUI emacs -- I find the highlighting a lot easier to see at a glance than the little arrow fringe marker):

```
(defun my/turn-on-hl-line-mode ()
  (hl-line-mode 1))
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook #'my/turn-on-hl-line-mode)
(defun my/update-compilation-hl-line ()
  (with-current-buffer next-error-last-buffer
    (when hl-line-mode (hl-line-highlight))))
(add-hook 'next-error-hook 'my/update-compilation-hl-line)
```